# Running Django (v1.9) unit test as given in official tutorials fails with 'Failed to import test module: polls.tests'

Tags: django, django-unittest

I'm following the tutorial given in the Django official website (Django v1.9 and python3). For executing the test in `polls\tests.py` the import to `polls.test` is failing.

```
E:\Django official tutorial\mysite>python manage.py test polls
Creating test database for alias 'default'...

ERROR: polls.tests (unittest.loader._FailedTest)

ImportError: Failed to import test module: polls.tests
```

Request help in resolving this issue.

Comment: is there `__init__.py` in your `polls` folder?

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko Yes. There is `__init__.py` in `polls` folder.

Comment: Do you have syntax errors in `polls.test`?

Comment: Is there an `__init__.py` in your `E:\Django official tutorial\mysite` directory? If there is, you should remove it. [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069880/running-django-tutorial-tests-fail-no-module-named-polls-tests) for more info.

Comment: @Alasdair verified that there in no '__init__.py' in the directory same as `manage.py`.

Comment: @ilse2005 there are no systax errors in polls.tests . Verified by checking the module.

Comment: Not sure if that's the case, but any blank spaces in your project path could lead to exceptions. Try renaming `Django official tutorial` to something else

Comment: @4140tm Tried changing the name of folder 'Django official tutorial' . Yet same issue :(

Comment: My bad. It was `polls\tests.py` that was failing to import a module. `manage.py` can run the unit tests now.