# PyCharm Django test ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: django, testing, pycharm, modulenotfounderror

Project tree:

```
|___sb_website
|   |___article
|   |   |__...py
|   |___home
|   |   |__...py
|   |___sb_website
|   |   |__dev_settings.py
|   |   |__...py
|   |__manage.py
|   |__...py
```

My django project development settings are `dev_settings.py`. I want to run my tests against these settings.

When I use a **Python configuration** in **PyCharm** with these parameters `test --settings=sb_website.dev_settings`, script path `..\sb_website\manage.py` I get the following Error:
`ERROR: sb_website.article (unittest.loader._FailedTest) ImportError: Failed to import test module: sb_website.article`.
Same for `sb_website.home` and `sb_website.sb_website`

If use a **Django Test configuration** in **PyCharm** modules are imported and tests run fine.

I'd like to learn the root cause of my problem as it is not the first time I faced this.

What I tried:
changed all imports to explicit imports, e.g. `*.models` to `home.models`

Comment: Try to change the test target until it works in your test configuration.

Comment: @vinkomlacic I only have the target in the django test config, in the python config I have Script path/Module name and parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not related to PyCharm, the answer why there was a difference between the **Python configuration** and **Django Test configuration** was that the **Python configuration** pointed directly to the test target. Django Test configuration uses the `manage.py test` command and executing it tried to import tests and found a `__init__.py` in the root folder.

By removing the `__ini__.py` in my root folder of `sb_website` the modules were found correctly and tests ran through.
The answer was found here [Running django tests fails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22096628/17843187)